# Python: Using dictionaries from parent class in subclass

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass

I want to use the dictionaries from the parent class "Graph"and use it in the subclass called "Summary".

The dictionaries are nodes, degree, neighbors, histogram, and graph.

The functions in Summary cannot be used when trying to use "graph.(tab completion)", so that is the problem I am running into.

I am new to python and programming in general, so I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible or not.

```
class Graph:
    '''docstring'''

    def __init__(self, graph):

        d = {}
        d1 = {}
        d2 ={}
        with myfile as f:
            next(f)
            for line in f:
                k, v = line.split()
                d[int(k)] = int(v)
                next(f)

            myfile.seek(0)

            data = [line.strip() for line in myfile]
            d1 = dict(enumerate(data))

            del d1[0]

            d2 = {key: list(map(int, value.split())) for key, value in d1.items()}

            i = 1
            while i <= max(d2.keys()):
                del d2[i]
                i += 2

            neighbors = dict(enumerate(d2.values(), start = 1))


        hist = defaultdict(list)
        for key, values in neighbors.iteritems():
            hist[len(values)].append(key)
        histogram = dict(hist)

        degree = d.values()
        nodes = d.keys()

        self.graph = graph
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.degree = degree
        self.neighbors = neighbors
        self.histogram = histogram

class Summary(Graph):
    def __init__(self, graph):
        Graph.__init__(self, graph)

    def Avg_Connectivity(self):


        return ("Average Node Connectivity:", np.average(self.degree))

    def Max_Connectivity(self):

        return ("Maximum Node Connectivity:" , max(self.degree)),("Node with Maximum Connectivity:", self.nodes[self.degree.index(max(self.degree))]) 

    def Min_Connectivity(self):
        return ("Minimum Node Connectivity:", min(x for x in self.histogram.keys() if x != 0)),("Nodes with Minimum Connectivity", self.histogram[min(x for x in self.histogram.keys() if x != 0)])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import numpy as np
    from collections import defaultdict
    infile = raw_input("Enter File Name (e.g. e06.gal): ")
    myfile = open(infile, 'r')
    graph = Graph(myfile)
```

Comment: this is a strange design.  why does `Summary` inherit from `Graph`?  a summary isn't a graph; you make a summary _of_ a graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments, you're not using `Summary` anywhere.  You have a `Graph` object.  A subclass "adds" new methods to an existing class, but they only exist in the *new* class, not the one you inherit from.

Inheritance is a poor choice for this problem anyway; a "summary" is not a special case of a "graph".  You want a separate object that *wraps* a graph.

```
class Summary(object):
    def __init__(self, graph):
        self.graph = graph

    def avg_connectivity(self):
        return ("Average Node Connectivity:", np.average(self.graph.degree))

    # ... etc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import numpy as np
    infile = raw_input("Enter File Name (e.g. e06.gal): ")
    myfile = open(infile, 'r')
    graph = Graph(myfile)
    summary = Summary(graph)
```

Adjust the other methods to use `self.graph` rather than properties on `self` directly.  Now `summary` will have the methods you want.

Some other comments on your code:

- You have very, very long lines.  You can wrap anywhere in parentheses, or use temporary variables instead of the same long expression twice.
- `Foo_Bar` is a very unusual way to style a name; just keep it lowercase.
- Your `Graph` constructor takes an open file (confusingly named `graph`), and then keeps ahold of it as `self.graph`.  You probably don't need to do this.
- Your variable names in general are kind of hard to understand: `d` vs `d1` vs `d2`, and `hist` vs `histogram`.  Comments would help too.
- You should put your `import` at the top of the file, not in this block at the bottom.
- Does this file format have pairs of lines?  Reading that is a little complicated; I sympathize  :)

Comment: Wow, you have left my speechless.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In general, `Summary` inherits all fields and methods from `Graph`. So you are able to access `self.graph` or `self.nodes` in `Summary`. Have you tried to access these fields? If it did not work, what was the error?

Comment: The functions in Summary do not become available when I do, graph.(tab completion).

Comment: 1. Did you try `self.graph`?  2. What editor do you use?  3. It is possible that code completion does not work but the code is correct nevertheless.

Comment: I am using Ipython console.

When I do graph.(tab completion), all of the dictionaries I created in the first class show up and output nicely.

Comment: i think you misunderstand inheritance.  `graph` is a `Graph`, not a `Summary`.  it doesn't know anything about `Summary`.

Comment: @Eevee, So in the Graph class there are dictionaries I want to use in the Summary subclass.

I am able to make it work with all of it in once class but I am suppose to use multiple classes.

Comment: you're not using the `Summary` class anywhere.

Comment: @Eevee, so you are saying that I need to use Summary the same way I used Graph at the very bottom of the code?

Comment: why did you do it like this, and where are you learning Python?  i don't know what your thought process is and i'd like you to walk away understanding what's going on, not just having working code.

Comment: @Eevee, I'm taking a data file and chopping it up in two different algorithms and outputting 4 dictionaries; nodes, degree, neighbors, histogram. I then want to create a subclass that takes those dictionaries and use them in the functions created in the subclass to output information about the dictionaries. I have been able to make this all work nice and good with all of my code in one class, but I am suppose implement the concept of "inheritance".